# Enterprise Architect Add-in, how to display log message

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm writing a .NET add-in for Sparx Enterprise Architect and wish to log messages to the 'System Output' window or the add-in window.

*What I tried:*
The `Console.Write` and `Trace.Write` methods don't display in the EA gui.
EA scripting allows writing messages through the `Session.Output(...)` method but the Interop.EA.dll doesn't seem to expose the Session interface. Popping up a message box with custom text works but doesn't suit displaying log messages.

*One* reason for displaying a running log this is to show progress and warnings to the user. So as a fall-back solution, I would be happy to display a progress bar or even an hourglass.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `EA.Repository.WriteOutput()`

See https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/add-ins___scripting/repository3.html for the documentation of that method.

Before you do, you might want to create the tab, clear it, and make it visible.

```
EA.Repository.CreateOutputTab()
EA.Repository.ClearOutput()
EA.Repository.EnsureOutputVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Geert's answer, here's a piece of code that tests logging. I commonly run and test code in LINQPad before putting it into production. This does the trick:

```
int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("EA").First().Id;
var repo = SparxSystems.Services.GetRepository(pid);

const string logwindowName = "juridical logger";
repo.CreateOutputTab(logwindowName);
repo.ClearOutput(logwindowName);
repo.EnsureOutputVisible(logwindowName);
repo.WriteOutput(logwindowName, "ignorantia juris non excusat", 0);
```

A screenshot with LINQPad and EA in the background to prove the point:

[image]